# Java: updating hashsets of hashsets

Tags: java, set, hashset

In the example below, the `BigSet` HashSet is made up of `SmallSet` HashSets. I'd like to clear `SmallSet` without clearing `BigSet`.

Instead, when I perform the `clear()` command on `SmallSet`, `BigSet` is also cleared. Why does this happen? And how can I only clear `SmallSet`, while leaving `BigSet` intact?

I've included print statements to illustrate what is going on.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class G{
    public static final HashSet<HashSet> BigSet = new HashSet <HashSet>();
    public static final HashSet<Set> SmallSet = new HashSet<Set>();

    public static Set<Integer> method() {
        Set<Integer> n = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30));
        SmallSet.add(n);
        BigSet.add(SmallSet);
        System.out.println(SmallSet);
        System.out.println(BigSet);
        SmallSet.clear();
        System.out.println(SmallSet);
        System.out.println(BigSet);
        return n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[[20, 10, 30]]
[[[20, 10, 30]]]
[]
[[]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `SmallSet` to `BigSet` you add the set itself, not the set inside it. So you could either

```
BigSet.add(new HashSet(SmallSet));
```

or

```
BigSet.addAll(SmallSet);
```

I personally recommend the later.

Note however, that because you're adding the `Set` to small set, if you did the following:

```
    Set<Integer> n = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30));
    SmallSet.add(n);
    BigSet.addAll(SmallSet);
    n.remove(20);
    System.out.println(BigSet);
```

You would get `[10, 30]` because it's the SET and not the SET'S ELEMENTS that were added to `BigSet`.

Also, when I was working on things like this in school, I was strongly encouraged to "draw boxes" - physical boxes on a chalkboard or whiteboard or paper. In this case you might even want to use note cards and putting them on top of each other to show what is in where. It really helps wrap your brain around it.

Comment: OP says that bigSet is a set containing sets. I don't think OP is looking for the elements to be adding.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. BigSet.add(new HashSet(SmallSet)) is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I will say that `BigSet.add(new HashSet...)` and `BigSet.addAll(...)` do the exact same thing, but addAll is twice as fast because it doesn't have to dump from `SmallSet` into the `new HashSet`. I highly recommend `addAll` over `add(new`

Answer (score 1):

You are not correct that you are clearing `bigSet` when you clear `smallSet`. `smallSet` is still inside `bigSet`, it's just that's it's now empty (because you cleared it). So when you see `[[]]` from the print statement it is telling you that `bigSet` now contains a single, empty set (specifically the now empty `smallSet`).

I suspect your misunderstanding is that you are imagining that `bigSet` is taking a copy of `smallSet` when you add it. It isn't. It's adding a reference to the same object referred to by the variable `smallSet`. When you call `smallSet.clear` you are clearing the set object referenced both by the variable and by `bigSet`.

If you actually wanted a copy of `smallSet` inside `bigSet` the simplest thing to do would be to create a new set instead of clearing `smallSet`:

```
bigSet.add(smallSet);
smallSet = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: You're right; this is exactly what I  was trying to say. I guess the solution is a new HashSet of SmallSet, as you're saying. Thanks